# How can I reuse i18n translation keys in Angular?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm using the i18n support for Angular2 (4.0.3) as documented [here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n). I've generated the `xlf` files and everything is working happily.

However, let's say that I have a menu button that links to my home page. I create the DOM node using the attribute `i18n="@@homeTitle"`. Now, in my home page component, I'd like to use the *same translation ID* in my `<h1>` tag, so that I get the same translation without having to maintain multiple entries with the same content in the `xlf` files.

I had hoped to do something like the below, and have it auto-populate my `<a>` node with the appropriate translation.

```
// home.component.html
<h1 i18n="@@homeTitle">Home</h1>

// menu.component.html
<a routerLink="/" i18n="@@homeTitle"></a>
```

However, this does not work. The `<a>` node shows up with empty text, not the translation target. (Further, by default there is no translation target in the auto-generated `messages.xlf` file.)

The docs actually [call out this situation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#set-a-custom-id-to-improve-search-and-maintenance) but do not offer a solution. The issue was also called out by a user [on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12941#issuecomment-262305433) for common strings like *Monday* and *cancel*, but that issue thread does not cover a solution to this particular problem.

**How can I reuse i18n translations defined in my `xlf` files across multiple nodes?**

*Edit: Here is the `xlf` generated by using `ng-xi18n --i18nFormat=xlf`:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="homeTitle" datatype="html">
        <source>Home</source>
        <target/>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

*If the parsing order of the two `@@homeTitle` nodes is switched, `<source>` changes respectively.*

Comment: Could you perhaps show the associated xlf ?
Also what do you use to extract the translations key and generate the xlf ?

Comment: @Romain I've added the `xlf`, though I'm not sure it'll be of much use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TLDR**; Just don't worry about custom IDs and write your strings correctly. The `ng xi18n` tool will take care of matching the identical strings under a single `<trans-unit>`. Your translations will then be applied to the whole unit.

The longer explanation: The `xi18n` tool matches strings in your app by string equality. Whenever it finds a new string, it compares it to the already found ones. If there is an exact match, it includes the new string in an existing `<trans-unit>`. If there is not, it creates a new one and generates a new ID.

This behaviour, however, can be changed by using custom IDs and translation hints. If a new string is found and contains a custom ID, the current messages will be checked for this particular ID and assigned to an existing `<trans-group>`, if found. Note, that this process disregards the string itself, so any *non-empty* value will be merged into the found `<trans-group>` with the custom ID. Empty strings are omitted.

As the documentation mentions, only the first element with custom ID will be inspected for the *source* string. When there is a second element with the same ID, it's string value will not be parsed. This means that you could alter your solution to have all the other nodes with your custom ID contain a placeholder string. The localization would then work as you expect.

```
// home.component.html
<h1 i18n="@@homeTitle">Home</h1>
// menu.component.html
<a routerLink="/" i18n="@@homeTitle">ANY PLACEHOLDER STRING YOU WANT</a>
```

As you might see, this doesn't look particularly fancy. Moreover, you have to remember the custom ID for further re-use. I'd suggest not doing that, unless absolutely necessary. In my opinion, it is easier to just write the string (in your case `"Home"`), slap an `i18n` attribute onto the element and don't worry about re-use, since it will be done automatically. I'd use custom IDs mainly in case you need to have multiple varying (contextual) translations of one string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have a concern with just using the standalone `i18n` attribute: Let's say I use some string in ten places (maybe the term *Cancel* on modals). Then I decide I want to change that word in all locations (e.g. all *Cancel* to *No*). I now have to find all ten strings and replace them all. If they're all under one ID, I only have to make one change. As for your ID-matching idea, I explicitly mentioned that this doesn't work. When using the default locale, `ANY PLACEHOLDER STRING YOU WANT` would appear.

Comment: Well, yeah. What would be a good practice then is to have the default strings not be a locale per-se, but a template for all the locales. Even if your default language is English, you would still generate `messages.xlf` but then create `messages.en.xlf` out of these (providing the translations in there - most of them would be the same strings). Check [this tutorial](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/wiki/Tutorial-for-using-xliffmerge-with-angular-cli) for a way of how you mighe be able to do it easily.

Comment: I guess I'm rather disappointed that this is the best solution. Having to maintain a translation file for the default language seems a bit silly when this kind of functionality should be built in. Ah well, maybe it will be addressed in future versions of Angular.